# How can I use a view on site2 that consumes data from site1?

Tags: views, 8

We have a Drupal site that exposes a JSON API for users (http://site1/api/users).

We need to create on site2 a view of users based on the data provided by site1. (We cannot store the users on site2).

How can I use a view on site2 that consumes data from site1? Which hook should I use? What approach should I follow?

Comment: I don't know your setup and reasons but sounds like you should create content type and write a migration that will pull data from site 1 to site 2 and create a cron worker to run the migration periodically. Then you can create any view you like for those entities.

Comment: I cannot import all the users, we don't want to duplicate users in the site2. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @DenisKolmerschlag, Good question! have you found a way to do this?

Comment: @Hedeshy i changed job before we implement that. I assume my collegue did not use views and made a full custom module that read the data and display them using a custom theme hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [External Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/external_entities/) module can help you in this task.

> This module allow you to connect to datasets from external databases
>   and use it in your Drupal 8 website. While content lives external,
>   Drupal sees those remote entities as internal. This makes it possible
>   to alter the field displays, add references, comments, pathaliases,
>   share buttons, webshop products and more.

You can read to [Drupalize remote data with external entities](http://rodrigoaguilera.gitlab.io/external-entities-talk/#/).

Comment: The link is not working, can you share some more info, please? The module has no documentation.

Comment: @Hedeshy I changed the link to other that works.